# RaspberryPi access point on wlan1 stopped working

Tags: linux, networking, wifi

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 with an external WiFi antenna wlan1 set up as an independent IoT access point without Internet connection following [this tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-wifi-access-point/install-software), using hostap and isc-dhcp server. I omitted the Network Access Translation part.
The AP worked well up to the point when I tried connecting wlan0 to my router at home for accessing the Internet via the GUI.

My `/etc/network/interfaces` looks like this

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa/supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet static
    address 192.168.42.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

I setup the daemon

```
sudo service hostapd start
sudo service isc-dhcp-server start
```

and

```
sudo update-rc.d hostapd enable
sudo update-rc.d isc-dhcp-server enable
```

and this all worked before I started messing with wlan0.... But now on boot when hovering over the GUI it says "wlan1: Disassociated from Pi3AP" and `sudo service hostapd status` prints

```
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/hostapd)
Active: active (exited) since ... 31 mins ago
Process: 571 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/hostapd start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

The command

```
sudo service isc-dhcp-server status
```

returns an error

```
raspberrypi dhcpd[778]: receive_packet failed on wlan1: Network is down
```

When I run

```
sudo /usr/sbin/hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
```

all works again but nothing on reboot. Can someone spot at where the error lies? Somehow the network GUI and/or the two wlan interfaces seem to be interfering with each other.

Comment: try to add `denyinterfaces wlan1` to `/ect/dhcpcd.conf`. That should stop `dhcpcd` tying to do anything on `wlan1`

Comment: @Mero Wouldn't the line `iface wlan1 inet static` already prevent that?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev As far as I know, no. `dhcpcd` will keep try to obtain ip address.

Comment: @Mero But then, what's the purpose of `iface wlan1 inet dhcp`?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev This might answer your question. http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/39785/dhcpcd-vs-etc-network-interfaces. So I believe  dhcpcd start after networking and by default it will take over all interfaces. In order to stop that happening, you need to tell `dhcpcd` to do not do anything on that interface

Comment: To the OP: read [this](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37920/how-do-i-set-up-networking-wifi-static-ip-address) post (especially *Setup a Static IP Address* section) and see if that helps.