# Setting up a DHCP server on a Pi v3B with Raspbian Jessie?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, networking, raspbian-jessie, dhcp

I'm attempting to set up a Pi as a DHCP server for a private network of ~10 machines. The pi will be connected to a network switch.

So far I've been following this well written guide:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/networking-lessons/lesson-3/plan/

However, it starts talking about dnsmasq, which doesn't appear in my Raspbian version.

Reading around some [other](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/48466) [questions](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/39785/48466), I get the feeling that there was a change in configuration method with the Jessie release.

I have the following in `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
#iface eth0 inet dhcp
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.0.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

What do I need to do, if anything, with `dhcpcd.conf`?

**What is best practice for setting up a DHCP server on a Pi v3B with Raspbian Jessie?**

EDIT - in writing this question I realised that I had scrolled past some vital the install `dnsmasq` pre-requisite. It worked well. I've decided to post anyway to see if there are other viewpoints on this.

Comment: Why do you want t setup DHCP server? What is wrong with the one in your network switch? Have you disabled `dhcpcd`? The tutorial tells you to install `dnsmasq`.

Comment: @Milliways the network switch doesn't have one. Also, later, I'll want the pi to run a script in relation to the ip addresses it dishes out. And you're right the answer to my question is to follow the tutorial - however maybe there are some alternatives with advantages (e.g. not requiring prior internet connection) so worth leaving the question here imho.