# Raspberry 2B multiple static wifi connections

Tags: pi-2, wifi, raspbian-jessie

I have a problem cofiguring Raspberry's 2B wifi connection. I have a usb wifi adapter that is detected by raspberry. What I want to achive is to connect to wifi immediately after boot. I need only to connect to two diffrent wifi connections: one at home, and one when using Android phone as a modem. Also i want IP in home to be static

my `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` looks like this:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
ssid="Name of home wifi"
psk="home wifi pass"
proto=RSN
key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
pairwise=CCMP
auth_alg=OPEN
id_str="home"
}

network={
ssid="android phone wifi name"
psk="android wifi pass"
proto=RSN
key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
pairwise=CCMP
auth_alg=OPEN
id_str="android"
}
```

and my `/etc/network/interfaces` looks like this

```
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto wlan0

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
iface home inet static
address 192.168.1.155
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
iface android inet static
address 192.168.43.155
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.43.1
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert in using `wpa_supplicant` but you seem to mix some things:

You have only one ethernet interface (there you plug your cable in): `eth0`

I suppose you do also have only one wifi adapter / interface: `wlan0`

I guess you do not have any interfaces named `home` or `android`. It looks to me like if you are trying to create static IP's. Depending on the wifi that you connect to, you want to have different IP's. I do not know how to solve this. But I am pretty sure that it is not done in the way you are doing it actl.

Rewrite your `/etc/network/interfaces`. But first create a backup of that file `cp /etc/network/interfaces /etc/network/interfaces_backup`:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0 
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Now with `iface wifi0 inet dhcp` you should recieve an IP assigned from the dhcp-server of the router. To test your configuration on this command should do the job: `sudo wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -D wext -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -d` If you can establish the connection reboot and check if it does automatically.

If you are interested in the different options of `wpa_supplicant.conf` check this file: https://media-cdn.ubuntu-de.org/wiki/attachments/44/28/wpa_supplicant.conf.examples

Edit:

One more thing to note: Depending on your Linux version you might need to do configurations in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` [dhcpcd vs /etc/network/interfaces](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/39785/dhcpcd-vs-etc-network-interfaces#41187)

To find out info about your Linux: `uname -a` and `lsb_release -a`