# How to correctly restart wpa_supplicant debug with networkd-systemd?

Tags: wifi, systemd, debug

I am trying to debug setting up wifi with networkd-systemd managing wpa_supplicant.  The overall objective is to get wifi AP and managed client modes working at the same time.  I can get managed client working.  I can't get the AP mode working.

To help achieve the objective I want to restart both networkd and wpa_supplicant in debug modes.  Research with Google found a number of different answers.  It appears that some of those answers are now out of date.

From what I can find, the commands

```
systemctl stop networking.service
systemctl restart networking.service
```

do a normal stop/restart but I have also found this command

```
systemctl restart systemd-networkd
```

The following is mish/mash from different answers to get debug turned on but I don't know if it is the best or correct way to get into debug mode.

```
systemctl stop wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service
systemctl stop systemd-networkd.service

wpa_supplicant -dd -u -f $LOG -B
echo Running wpa-supplicant in debug mode.
```

(Edit)
The OS is Raspbian Stretch-Lite.
I have removed networkmanager from the above code.

Comment: I am using Raspbian

Comment: Stretch Lite.  It is a headless system.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First to shine a light on this mish/mash of different commands. On Raspbian there are three concurrent network environments installed: old style debian **networking** with `ifupdown` is configured in `etc/network/interfaces` but it is deprecated. The default networking environment of Raspbian is managed by **dhcpcd** and configured in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`. Old style *networking* is configured to give *dhcpcd* precedence but if it is used it partial overwrites settings from *dhcpcd*.

And there is a third network environment sleeping in the background: **systemd-networkd** that is managed with files in directory `/etc/systemd/network/`. It is there because it is build-in to *systemd*, the default init system of Raspbian. It is not very good to manage mobile devices but with static devices it is very powerful. To use it you have to completely [switch over to systemd-networkd](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/108593/79866) and disable both other networking systems.

And to make it a bit more confusing: all three networking systems using wifi manager `wpa_supplicant` as helper, each in an other way.

First of all you have to decide what networking system you want to use. The services of all three systems are managed by *systemd*, of course. With

```
rpi ~$ systemctl <command> networking.service
```

you manage old style *networking* service. With

```
rpi ~$ systemctl <command> dhcpcd.service
```

you manage *dhcpcd* service, and with

```
rpi ~$ systemctl <command> systemd-networkd.service
```

You manage that service. *wpa_supplicant* is only good managed and integrated in *systemd* when using *systemd-networkd* with:

```
rpi ~$ systemctl <command> wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service
```

I don't know how good it can be managed with *networking* by using

```
rpi ~$ systemctl <command> wpa_supplicant.service
```

but with *dhcpcd* the *wpa_supplicant* service is definitely not manageable with *systemd*. With *dhcpcd* the command

```
rpi ~$ systemctl status wpa_supplicant.service
```

shows you that it is disabled but in real it is active to manage wifi.

Now to come to debugging. If you really want to do that in general you can look at [www/Software/systemd/Debugging](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Debugging/). For *systemd-networkd* only you can improve its log level by setting an environment variable for this service.

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl edit systemd-networkd.service
```

and insert this into the empty editor, save and quit it:

```
[Service]
Environment=SYSTEMD_LOG_LEVEL=debug
```

This will improve the log messages from *systemd-networkd* into the journal. You can get them with:

```
rpi ~$ journalctl --boot --unit=systemd-networkd
```

Don't forget to disable improved logging with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo rm -r /etc/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service.d/
```

For debugging *wpa_supplicant* you do it the best in the forground because you have a lot of output. First look what command is executed by the service with:

```
rpi ~$ systemctl cat wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service
```

You will find a line something like:

```
ExecStart=/sbin/wpa_supplicant -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-%I.conf -Dnl80211,wext -i%I
```

Replace placeholder %I with **wlan0**, add the debug option `-d` and start it:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl stop wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service
rpi ~$ sudo /sbin/wpa_supplicant -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf -Dnl80211,wext -iwlan0 -d
```

Comment: This is broadly correct, but both Debian networking and dhcpcd will both allocate addresses (if anyone is silly enough to attempt this) - with unpredictable results, although they can be used in parallel on different interfaces. dhcpcd will disable itself if it discovers another system calling dhcp. dhcpcd has its own hook to call wpa_supplicant, but this was omitted in Jessie.

Comment: @Milliways Yes I know, but it all doesn't matter with *systemd-networkd*. I only wanted to give an overview without much details like [dhcpcd vs /etc/network/interfaces](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/41187/79866).

Comment: For HypriotOS (Raspbian-based), is there something else to consider in the ways network is managed ? cloud-init is now used on HypriotOS.

Comment: @Uriel Because HypriotOS is a Raspbian derivate it should also have three network environments. But I don't know HypriotOS and what networking system it uses.

Comment: Without drawing you too far *off course*, can you explain briefly how `systemd-resolved` fits in with all of this, and why it's not used on RPi? Don't waste much time on this... and if you'd prefer, I can post it as a new question.

Comment: @Seamus Yes, please ask a question. There are some sentences to say with example.

Comment: Any reference about the deprecation of `/etc/network/interfaces`? Debian Wiki doesn't mention this.

Comment: @Ruslan We are on Raspberry Pi OS, not Debian. RasPiOS uses `dhcpcd`, not `ifupdown`. You can find a hint in `/etc/network/interfaces` itself: "*# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd # For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf*".'

Comment: Incredibly helpful, and incredibly confusing set of system resources.  not sure even where to start just to log db levels and status of my wifi network to a rotating log.   I'm thinking I just do this via Python and logrotate.  Not seeing any simple way to just ride on other monitoring activities.

Comment: @leeprevost I don't know what exactly you want to achieve, but have had a look at the [systemd-journald.service](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/systemd-journald.service.8.html)?

Comment: @ingo. No but thank you.   I will