# Pi Zero: eth0 not added to bridge after reboot

Tags: raspbian, pi-zero-w, raspbian-buster, access-point, bridge

I've follow [the official guide](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md) to setup a bridge between `eth0` und `wlan0` in order to use my Pi Zero WH as an AP with raspbian buster 4.19.75+.

When I add the interface `brctl addif br0 eth0`, the bridge works fine. However after reboot, `eth0` consistently isn't a member of `br0`. The system then looks the following:

```
root@raspberrypi:~# brctl show
bridge name  bridge id          STP enabled  interfaces
br0          8000.b827eb885a93  no           wlan0

root@raspberrypi:~# cat /etc/systemd/network/bridge-br0.netdev
[NetDev]
Name=br0
Kind=bridge

root@raspberrypi:~# cat /etc/systemd/network/bridge-br0-slave.network
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
Bridge=br0

root@raspberrypi:~# cat /etc/systemd/network/bridge-br0.network
[Match]
Name=br0

[Network]
Address=10.5.5.13/24
Gateway=10.5.5.1
DNS=10.5.5.1
DNS=8.8.8.8
DNS=8.8.4.4
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The Pi Zero has no ethernet device - perhaps the problem is with whatever USB ethernet device you're trying to use - for example, for some reason it's not detected by systemd

Comment: How do you get an interface **eth0**? Do you use an additional USB/ethernet dongle?

Comment: yes, I'm using a USB/ethernet adapter which is working without issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't use [the official guide](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md). They are horribly mixing up things, setups and helper programs without understanding what they are doing. Beside other things they use configuration of interfaces with files in `/etc/systemd/network`. To use these files you have to enable **systemd-networkd** which is managing these files. For further information you may have a look at [Compare three available networking systems on Raspbian](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/89729/79866).

Now if you check your setup you have made with the buggy guide with:

```
rpi ~$ systemctl status systemd-networkd.service
```

you will see that it is disabled! So this cannot work. And no, it does not help to just enable it. This will interfere with **dhcpcd** and maybe with the **bridge-utils**.

You can use [Setting up a Raspberry Pi as an access point - the easy way](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/88234/79866) to get a tested and running access point.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the links, I will work through them. It's mind-boggling that the official guide get's this so wrong, I considered it to be the most reliable...

Comment: Grosses Danke Ingo, your walkthrough worked flawlessly and I've got my bridge running!

Comment: @Morrow The official guide is **NOT WRONG**. If you use the officially supported `dhcpcd` the guides work. There is nothing wrong with using a different networking service, but you will have to get used to reading the `man` pages.

Comment: @Milliways The brigde part is **DEFINITIVELY WRONG**. Please note that they changed the setup and try to use configuration with files in `/etc/systemd/network` but they don't start **systemd-networkd** that is needed for that. Please try that setup and you will find that **eth0** isn't added to the bridge.

Comment: @Milliways I can attest to the guides' falsity in the current state. I started this very thread because the bridge didn't work after following the official guide meticulously. Try it yourself if you are not convinced.

Comment: @Ingo I've found [this updated guide](https://github.com/raspberrypi/documentation/blob/e134af42dda5ea15d530f2743240e7c18abc4894/configuration/wireless/access-point-bridged.md) in a pending pull request. Is this one correct now?

Comment: @Morrow Yes, looks better. They have realized to enable `systemd-networkd` and they must not use bridge-utils because of conflicts. But they still mixing up `systemd-networkd` and `dhcpcd` and they use not needed `hostapd`.