# My Raspberry Pi cannot connect to the Internet. etc/network/interfaces file does not appear

Tags: wifi

I am trying to connect my Raspberry pi 1 model b to the internet using an Edimax adapter. My pi recognises the adapter, but when I try to configure my pi to connect to my WIFI by using

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

My screen comes up with:

```
# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd.
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'.
```

and some other comments. When I use the command:

```
sudo nano /etc/dhcpcd.conf
```

The following appears:

```
# A sample configuration for dhcpcd.
# See dhcpcd.conf(5) for details.

# Allow users of this group to interact with dhcpcd via the control socket.
#controlgroup wheel

# Inform the DHCP server of our hostname for DDNS. 
hostname

# Use the hardware address of the interface for the Client ID.
clientid
# or
# Use the same DUID + IAID as set in DHCPv6 for DHCPv4 ClientID as per 
RFC4361.
#duid

# Persist interface configuration when dhcpcd exits.
persistent

# Rapid commit support.
# Safe to enable by default because it requires the equivalent option set
# on the server to actually work.
option rapid_commit

# A list of options to request from the DHCP server.
option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name
option classless_static_routes
# Most distributions have NTP support.
option ntp_servers
# Respect the network MTU.
# Some interface drivers reset when changing the MTU so disabled by 
default.
#option interface_mtu
```

lsusb comes up with:

```
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 046:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 7392:7811 Edimax Technology Co., Ltd EW-7811Un 802.11n Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8188CUS] 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9524 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMC9514 Hub 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

ifconfig comes up with (For the wlan0 section):

```
wlan0: flags=4099<UP, BROADCAST MULTICAST> mtu 1500 
ether 74:da:38:ed:45:e9 txqueuelen 1000 (Ethernet) 
RX packets 0 bytes 0 (0.0 B)
RX errors 0 dropped 12 overruns 0 frame 0 TX packets 0 bytes 0 (0.0 B) 
TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0
```

I really am not sure what to do from here. 
I do apologise if this is an obvious problem, but I am new to Raspberry Pi, so if you could explain to me in a simple way how to configure the Wifi network I would really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: What OS? If you are using Raspbian just select your network from the GUI. See [How to set up networking/WiFi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

Comment: I am using Raspbian, but my Pi doesn't recognise any networks in the GUI. I have just plugged in the Wi-Fi adapter and booted it up once with it in - I still need to configure it to the desired Wifi network

Comment: Another thing to note - my nano is v2.7.4

Comment: Please add details of your dongle to the question, including the output of `lsusb` and `ifconfig`. And what protocol does your AP use? Is the SSID of the AP hidden?

Comment: From the listings you give us there is no problem with your usb wifi dongle. Raspbian sees it as normal wifi interface **wlan0** so you should be able to use it. Additional you can verify if it works with `sudo iw list`, `sudo iw dev` and `sudo iw dev wlan0 scan`. Just with the last command you should see all the wifi networks from your neighbors. If so then it is only a configuration issue. Follow the instructions *Milliways* gives in his first comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this has nothing to do with your nano, but you have to modify other files. I will take a part of an answer from [this post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/39785/dhcpcd-vs-etc-network-interfaces). As is stated, there was some confusion when updating from Wheezy to Jessie, regarding `interfaces` and `dhcpcd.conf` files for configuring networks.

> When to use which file?
>
> I'm going to make the assumption that you are
>   suffering from a general degree of confusion that is occurring at the
>   moment (in the wider Raspberry Pi community) with the introduction of
>   Debian 'Jessie' in place of Debian 'Wheezy'. This change has made a
>   large number of tutorials at worst obsolete and at best confusing.
>
> The answer to the question is that when using Wheezy it was normal to
>   make changes to the /etc/network/interfaces file for the purposes of
>   setting up network interfaces (go figure). When using Jessie, it will
>   be necessary to make changes to '/etc/dhcpcd.conf'. However, if making
>   changes to a wireless connection (wlan0) you will also need to make
>   changes to /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf which is where you
>   add the network ssid and password.

---

- Add to `dhcpcd.conf` file:

`interface wlan0
    static ip_address=192.168.0.10/24 # Your static IP configuration
    static routers=192.168.0.1 # Your default gateway
    static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.1 8.8.8.8 # DNS servers`

- Edit the file `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` adding this to the bottom:

`network={
        ssid="YOUR_SSID"
        psk="YOUR_PASSWORD"
    }`

- Reconfigure the interface using `wpa_cli -i wlan0 reconfigure` or reboot

[This post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37920/how-do-i-set-up-networking-wifi-static-ip-address) will give you a deeper explanation if you need it.

Comment: A bit premature as an answer. The first question should be: is the dongle recognised and supported. If not, you can change all you want to any configuration file, but it will not make a difference. OP says the Pi recognises it, but I have not seen any proof yet.

Comment: The dongle I have gotten is compatible - Edimax N150.

Comment: Also, I have added in changes to /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf alone as stated in this tutorial - https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/39785/dhcpcd-vs-etc-network-interfaces - where else should I edit and what exactly should I do? Where in the /etc/dhcpcd.conf file should I make edits, and what should those edits look like? I really appreciate the help!

Comment: as @Dirk mentioned, the output of `lsusb`, `ifconfig` would be useful to help you. Also, do you need DHCP or static IP for your wireless configuration? You can add these details to your question.

Comment: I just need a static IP.

Comment: Output for lsusb -

Comment: Bus 001 Device 008: ID 046:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120                                   Bus 001 Device 004: ID 7392:7811 Edimax Technology Co., Ltd EW-7811Un 802.11n Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8188CUS]                                                         Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter                                                                         Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9524 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMC9514 Hub         Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Comment: ifconfig wlan0: flags=4099<UP, BROADCAST MULTICAST> mtu 1500                        ether 74:da:38:ed:45:e9 txqueuelen 1000 (Ethernet)                                                              RX packets 0 bytes 0 (0.0 B)

Comment: RX errors 0 dropped 12 overruns 0 frame 0                                                                                                     TX packets 0 bytes 0 (0.0 B)                                                                                                     TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0

Comment: Please put this additional information in your question.

Comment: I have done those changes, but what edits need to be made to /etc/dhcpcd.conf ?

Comment: @PedroHablespanyos So instead of connection problems it's actually about getting a static address? Anyway, see the first comment on your question by Milliways. It should give you all the information you need.

Comment: I realised I do not need static IP necessarily - rather just basic internet connection. I have made the above changes to /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf and it is not working. I have also looked at some more tutorials which say I can use the WiFi Config application to try connect it, however I do not have this app. When I try to get it using sudo apt install wpagui I get messages along the line of                  E: Failed to fetch (some raspbian website). I have tried to connect it in all these ways, including the top GUI, which still displays 'no wifi interfaces found'.

Comment: I am also really sorry for the lack of information - really my aim after all this is to be able to control my Pi remotely, and I am not too sure what exactly I need. I assume WiFi is required, but I just need a basic connection.