# Static IP address not working on Raspberry Pi with DHCPCD

Tags: pi-3, networking, static-ip

I created a static IP address for eth0 to use with a USB dongle (connected to my PC) in `dhcpcd.conf` file.

```
interface eth0
static ip_address=169.254.2.13/16
static routers=169.254.11.25
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly is your definition of "not working" here, and why would you use static addresses together with DHCPCD instead of one or the other?

Comment: I was looking up on how to create static address, and that came up.  Apparently, `/etc/network/interface` is the "old way"

Answer (score 1):

`169.254.2.13/16` is a [Link-local address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address)

This is not routable, and makes no sense.

Comment: I thought that was fine since it was possible with the old `/etc/interfaces` method?

Comment: No matter how you set it it is not routable

Comment: Although not best practice (link local addresses may well clash as are allocated for non-addressed devices by the OS) I do think it should work on a local network segment (though I could be wrong). OP - do you see the IP address assigned to the interface (through ifconfig for example), as if not then routing isn't even an issue yet.

Comment: Nothing showed up.  I decided to just use `/etc/network/interface`, even though it's the "old way"

Comment: If you decide to use `/etc/network/interfaces` then you should notice the second line in it: **Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd** and take care of [Differences between /etc/dhcpcd.conf and /etc/network/interfaces?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/39785/differences-between-etc-dhcpcd-conf-and-etc-network-interfaces).