# set ppp0 as default gateway permanently

Tags: ppp

I have a Zero W with a 4G module, to use the sim to access internet I did:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ip route
default via 10.111.100.1 dev wlan0 proto dhcp src 10.111.100.143 metric 302 
10.64.64.64 dev ppp0 proto kernel scope link src 10.82.126.194 
10.111.100.0/24 dev wlan0 proto dhcp scope link src 10.111.100.143 metric 302 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wwan0 scope link src 169.254.170.232 metric 203
```

then:

```
sudo ip route del default via 10.111.100.1 dev wlan0
sudo ip route add default via 10.64.64.64 dev ppp0
```

and it works, but after reboot I get the original situation...

I tried to set auto ppp0 in /etc/network/interfaces

I tried to set metric in /etc/dhcpcd.conf

but none worked.how can I do that?

also I have a PPTP VPN, how can start it automatically on system boot?

I'm on Raspbian Buster

Comment: What operating system do you use? Do you respect the special issues using `/etc/network/interfaces` together with **dhcpcd**?

Comment: I'm using Raspbian Buster, what do you mean with special issues?

Comment: Special issues are the note in `/etc/nettwork/interfaces` **# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd** and https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/41187/79866.

Comment: I still didn't set up anything in /etc/network/interfaces and /etc/dhcpcd.conf, I disabled wifi which I won't need, but after boot I still have wlan0 as default route, also I don't know how to start sudo pon myvpn on boot

Comment: You did not set up anything in `/etc/network/interfaces`? But you wrote "*I tried to set auto ppp0 in /etc/network/interfaces*" and "*I tried to set metric in /etc/dhcpcd.conf*".

Comment: yes but since it didn't work I came back to original files. anyway I solved adding route commands in /usr/src/reconnect.sh. now last thing is how to start vpn client on boot, I tried the script here https://prosindo.com/blog/2015/08/24/vpn-pptp-client-on-raspberry-pi/ and /etc/network/interfaces configuration here http://pptpclient.sourceforge.net/howto-debian.phtml but didn't work

Comment: You can't have more than one `default` network. That's the route the kernel uses to send packets that don't match any of the current subnets.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's your setup and what you have tried. But with a default networking setup a ppp connection will give the interface **ppp0** on the RasPi an ip address and a default route to the gateway of the ppp device by DHCP. So you should check why your ppp device isn't giving a default route.

In `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` you can also define static default routes with option **static routers=**. So ensure that all these options are commented to not overwrite the default route from the ppp device.

Look that `/etc/network/interfaces` does not contain any stanzas to configure ifupdown. This may have side effects to **dhcpcd**.