# What is the easiest way to set static ip in raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi-desktop

I want to do port fowarding of my raspberry Pi,  so first I need to set static ip. I searched in Google but didn't find any easy answer.

Comment: [How to set up Static IP Address](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/74428/8697)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using **Raspbian** then `dhcpcd` is used for network configuration. Just look into `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`. At the end you will find some examples for static IP configuration. For further information look at `man dhcpcd.conf`. For searching in Google you should use [raspbian static ip address](https://www.google.com/search?q=raspbian+static+ip+address).

Comment: How about etc/network/interfaces?  I saw in some article about that?!

Comment: Beware that older versions of Raspbian did not use `dhcpcd`, they used Debian's networking system; `/etc/network/interfaces` is part of the latter. If you are curious see `man interfaces` -- but do not use it, use `dhcpcd.conf`.

Comment: @goldilocks Do you wanted to address *Thetips4you*? Or do you asked me to update my answer and refer to an unsupported Raspbian version? If there are problems with Debian networking and dhcpcd I like to link to [Differences between /etc/dhcpcd.conf and /etc/network/interfaces?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/41187/79866).

Comment: Yeah, that last comment was to the OP, and no, I don't think you need to show two different ways to accomplish this if the simpler one (`dhcpcd.conf`) works.  Technically that comment (of mine) is a bit wrong in that you can make use of `/etc/network` stuff with the current dhcpcd service, but it isn't necessary here and may create unwanted complications.